# Oracle SQL - Extract some words only from a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, extract, cpu-word

I am working with Oracle SQL and I have a column with specific words that I want to extract. For example, I have:

```sql
MENACE DE MORT REITEREE EN RECIDIVE
VIOLENCES SUR CONJOINT
```

And I want to extract:

```sql
MENACE MORT
VIOLENCES CONJOINT
```

I've tried using `regex_replace` to replace specific words found in my list of words, but I have not been able to extract only the specific words.
Is there a way to do this? I have about 50 specific words to extract.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How could we know which words to extract? Where's the list?

Comment: It's a big list that I do not have yet since I don't know if I can do what I want to, but in this exemple, you could have this list : "MENACE", "MORT", "VIOLENCES", "CONJOINT"

Comment: I don't care about the contents, I wonder how it's provided - is it a separate table etc?

Comment: Ah ok sorry. It's manually

Comment: Manually?!? Put them in a table instead. It will save you lots of time in the end, and code will be unaffected if you need to add/remove words in the future.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't have rights to write on the dB. It's a read only access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case you will need a list of words (and probably some order of the wrords) to do the job. One of the options is to create a list of words and store them in a table. In this answer I will create CTE (words) as a sample. But first some sample data to work with:

```sql
WITH            --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (ID, TXT) AS
        (   
            Select 1, 'MENACE DE MORT REITEREE EN RECIDIVE' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'VIOLENCES SUR CONJOINT' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'MALTRAITANCE PSYCHOLOGIQUE SUR CONJOINT' From Dual
        ),
```

... and words list ...

```sql
    words_str AS
        (     
            Select '\MENACE\VIOLENCES\MALTRAITANCE\PSYCHOLOGIQUE\MORT\CONJOINT\' "WORDS_TO_RETURN" From Dual
        ), 
    words AS
        (
            Select  LEVEL "WORD_ID", SubStr(WORDS_TO_RETURN, InStr(WORDS_TO_RETURN, '\', 1, LEVEL) + 1, InStr(WORDS_TO_RETURN, '\', 1, LEVEL + 1) - InStr(WORDS_TO_RETURN, '\', 1, LEVEL) -1) "WORDS"
            From    words_str
            Connect By LEVEL <= Length(WORDS_TO_RETURN) - Length(Replace(WORDS_TO_RETURN, '\', '')) - 1
        )
```

| WORD_ID | WORDS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MENACE |
| 2 | VIOLENCES |
| 3 | MALTRAITANCE |
| 4 | PSYCHOLOGIQUE |
| 5 | MORT |
| 6 | CONJOINT |

You can now join your table with the words and truncate your text to the list of words from above...

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
SELECT  DISTINCT ID, TXT, 
        LISTAGG(WORDS, ' ') OVER(Partition By ID, TXT) "SHORT_TXT"
FROM   (   Select  t.ID, t.TXT,  w.WORD_ID, w.WORDS
           From tbl t
           Inner Join  words w ON(  InStr('\' || Replace(t.TXT, ' ', '\') || '\' , '\' || w.WORDS || '\') > 0 )
           Order By t.ID, w.WORD_ID
        )
ORDER BY ID
```

Result should be ...

| ID | TXT | SHORT_TXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MENACE DE MORT REITEREE EN RECIDIVE | MENACE MORT |
| 2 | VIOLENCES SUR CONJOINT | VIOLENCES CONJOINT |
| 3 | MALTRAITANCE PSYCHOLOGIQUE SUR CONJOINT | MALTRAITANCE PSYCHOLOGIQUE CONJOINT |

Comment: Perfect ! I had to add "within group (order by CPT)" for the LISTAGG but it works 5 stars. Thank you !

Comment: Edit : I think I found a small mistake. When TXT has only one word, for exemple "MENACE", the lign do not appear in the result.

Comment: @pfroide4 Please doublecheck the spelling and, maybe, extra spaces and compare it with inner join condition. I'm not at my computer untill tommorrow, but it is either joined or not (the word). If there is a join there shuld be the word within the ListAgg.

Comment: My bad. I've just noticed that the copy-paste was not 100% right :

Inner Join  words w ON(  InStr('\' || Replace(t.TXT, ' ', '\') || '\' , '\' || w.WORDS || '\') > 0 )

became

Inner Join  words w ON(  InStr(' \ ' || Replace(t.TXT, ' ', ' \ ') || ' \ ' , ' \ ' || w.WORDS || ' \ ') > 0 )

It works well, a big thank you. (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex and connect by to split the string into rows, and select the rows you want from that. Maybe store the values you want in a table and join to it.

```
with temp as  (
       select 1 as someID, 'MENACE DE MORT REITEREE EN RECIDIVE' as someStr  from dual
     )

select 

  someid,
  listagg(str, ' ') within group ( order by str) 
  from (
SELECT distinct someID ,trim(regexp_substr(someStr, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) str
  FROM (SELECT someID, someStr FROM temp) t
CONNECT BY instr(someStr, ' ', 1, level - 1) > 0
) t
  where
str in (
'MENACE' , 'MORT'
  )
group by
  someid
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8dMNylY-)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. The resultat is in rows, right ? Is it possible to obtain the result like this ?

`code`
SOMEID  SOMESTR
1          MENACE DE MORT REITEREE EN RECIDIVE

`code`
SOMEID   SOMESTR
1              MENACE MORT

Comment: You can combine them using `listagg` - see edited query

Comment: Thanks, it works well too but it is slower than the other solution above. Thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON target_table(target_column) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

And then instead of playing with CTE, recursive queries, and other goodies ...
just store the search expression (with boolean operators) in your "query" table: e.g. 'MENACE AND MORT', ...
(see doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/ccref/oracle-text-CONTAINS-query-operators.html#GUID-6410B783-FC9A-4C99-B3AF-9E0349AA43D1)
then

```
SELECT ... FROM target_table t, queries q
WHERE CONTAINS(t.target_column, q.query_column) > 0;
```